# I am not getting parameter values when calling AWS Lambda from C# code

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I am trying to call an [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda) function using the gateway URL from my C# code (which runs in another lambda function).

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "CompanyId", companyId.ToString() },
    { "ProjectId", projectId.ToString() }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

var response = client.PostAsync(awsGatewayUrl, content).Result;
```

The lambda function is called successfully, but it does not get the parameter values.

#### Function handler

```
public string FunctionHandler(RequestParams input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    Console.Write(input.CompanyId + "/" + input.ProjectId);
    if (input.CompanyId == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Required Param companyId is missing");
        return "function execution aborted";
    }

    // Do something else
    return "";
}
```

In the above code, if companyid and projectid is always missing.

I also tried

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
          .Accept
          .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    var json = new JObject
    {
        { "CompanyId", companyId },
        { "ProjectId", projectId }
    };

    var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = client.PostAsync(awsGatewayUrl, content).Result;
```

It still does not work.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that the request and response to a lambda function are wrapped in an event. For example, if you were to be using an HTTP Gateway, the event structure is as below

So to receive the payload, the event is required to be deserialized to an object that adheres to the defined structure. AWS SDK for .Net has [class definitions](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/README.md) for these events. Assuming that you are using HTTP API Gateway, the function handler should be defined as

```
public class Function
{
    public APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse Handler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apigProxyEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing request data for request {apigProxyEvent.RequestContext.RequestId}.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Body size = {apigProxyEvent.Body.Length}.");
        var headerNames = string.Join(", ", apigProxyEvent.Headers.Keys);
        Console.WriteLine($"Specified headers = {headerNames}.");

        return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
        {
            Body = apigProxyEvent.Body,
            StatusCode = 200,
        };
    }
}
```

[HTTP API Event Structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "routeKey": "$default",
  "rawPath": "/my/path",
  "rawQueryString": "parameter1=value1&parameter1=value2&parameter2=value",
  "cookies": [
    "cookie1",
    "cookie2"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "header1": "value1",
    "header2": "value1,value2"
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1,value2",
    "parameter2": "value"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "apiId": "api-id",
    "authentication": {
      "clientCert": {
        "clientCertPem": "CERT_CONTENT",
        "subjectDN": "www.example.com",
        "issuerDN": "Example issuer",
        "serialNumber": "a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1",
        "validity": {
          "notBefore": "May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT",
          "notAfter": "Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT"
        }
      }
    },
    "authorizer": {
      "jwt": {
        "claims": {
          "claim1": "value1",
          "claim2": "value2"
        },
        "scopes": [
          "scope1",
          "scope2"
        ]
      }
    },
    "domainName": "id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "domainPrefix": "id",
    "http": {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/my/path",
      "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
      "sourceIp": "192.0.2.1",
      "userAgent": "agent"
    },
    "requestId": "id",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "stage": "$default",
    "time": "12/Mar/2020:19:03:58 +0000",
    "timeEpoch": 1583348638390
  },
  "body": "Hello from Lambda",
  "pathParameters": {
    "parameter1": "value1"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "stageVariables": {
    "stageVariable1": "value1",
    "stageVariable2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: where should I define this gateway event handler?

Comment: In the lambda definition. The handler that you included in the question was accepting _RequestParams_ and _ILambdaContext_. Replace _RequestParams_ with _APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest_ and change the return type from _string_ to _APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse_ .